# Identify portrait or landscape mode and zoom level for mobile devices (but not specific to browsers)

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, landscape-portrait

I know one of the answer for identifying portrait or landscape node is -

```
window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight
```

But after 60th version of chrome, the definition of innerWidth and innerHeight has changed and now it represents layout viewport. 
So as soon as keypad is opened, although the device is in portrait mode,  window.innerHeight becomes smaller than window.innerWidth and it says it is landscape mode.

Also please note below things-

1. Don't want to put browser specific checks.
2. When orientation is changed some devices fire resize event too before 
   actually changing the orientation value.So, in that case in resize 
   callback, the orientation of device will actually be landscape but 
   orientation value will report it as portrait.
3. window.screen.orientation is also not compatible for different 
   browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use screen.width and screen.height, as they do not take into account whether or not the keyboard is visible, it simply returns the viewport dimensions.

```
let screenOrientation = () => {
  return screen.width > screen.height ? "landscape" : "portrait";
}
```

Comment: But ios and some other browsers doesn't change screen.width and screen.height when orientation is changed

Comment: @megha Sorry, it worked on my android, but couldn't check on mobile Safari. This article might be useful, though : https://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change

Answer (score 0):

You could use `outerWidth` instead of `innerWidth` to prevent any viewport stuff

```js
if (window.outerWidth > window.outerHeight) {
    //Landscape
}
```

Comment: It also changes when keypad is displayed and hence gives wrong result